# Accessing the previous state of a functional component with state being an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-state

Given that you can access the previous state when changing the current state by passing an arrow function like in the stopwatch function below:

```
function App() {
   const [time, setTime] = useState(0)

function counter() {
   setTime(prev => prev + 1)
}

return (
<div>
 <p>{time}<p>
 <button onClick={counter}>Click Me<button/>
</div>
)

}
```

Can I do the same when the state is an object? Is it a syntax issue I am having or it cannot be done?
What do I write where I have the question marks?

````
function App() {
   const [time, setTime] = useState({sec: 0, min: 0, hour: 0})

function stopwatch() {
   setTime(prev??? => ????)
}

return (
<div>
 <p>{time.sec} {time.min} {time.hour}<p>
 <button onClick={stopwatch}>Click Me<button/>
</div>
)

}

```
````

Comment: Just return a new object `setTime(prev=>({...prev, hour:prev.hour+1}))`. I just incremented hour for example...use your own logic to do what you need

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl ! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I just want to point out a small, subtle but important detail, with functional state updates. You are *actually* accessing the *current* state and returning the *next* state. Think of it as a super light "reducer", instead of (current state, action) => next state, you've (current state) => next state.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should try to make them separated, since minutes, seconds and hours increase in different moments. If you want to make a change in the minutes, for example, you can apply this logic to the object

```
function App() {
   const [time, setTime] = useState({sec: 0, min: 0, hour: 0})

function stopwatch() {
  setTime(prevTime => {
  return {
     ...prevTime,
     minutes: prevTimes.minutes + 1 // or you could directly change it..
  }  
})
}

return (
<div>
 <p>{time.sec} {time.min} {time.hour}<p>
 <button onClick={stopwatch}>Click Me<button/>
</div>
)

}
```

This logic can be applied to every number of changes you want to make, minutes, seconds and hours, just hours, etc.